# Using String Formatting in Python

Tags: python, string, formatting

I have a predetermined format

```
FORMAT = "{0:<30}{1}"
```

Which I want to use in relation to tuple x, where tuple x is something like

```
['bananas', '246']
```

I've tried everything I can, and it keeps spitting out errors. How do I use the format with my tuple?

EDIT: My expected output should (I think) simply put spaces between the first and second items, like

```
Bananas                                     246
```

I tried

```
x = FORMAT(x)
```

which gives

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: It's not tuple, it's a list.

Comment: Could you show your expected output for clarification?

Comment: right, got my terms a little off there

Comment: Don't try everything you can. Try the thing that is supposed to work, and if it doesn't, show us that code and the corresponding stack trace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) expects multiple arguments corresponding to the placeholders in the string being formatted, rather than a single argument that contains multiple items to be formatted. Therefore I think what you want is:

```
FORMAT.format(*['bananas', '246'])
```

where the `*` means "unpack the items in the iterable as separate positional arguments", i.e. effectively calls:

```
FORMAT.format('bananas', '246')
```

If your list is e.g.

```
x = ['bananas', '246']
```

then you can convert to a formatted string like:

```
x = FORMAT.format(*x)
```

Comment: When I use FORMAT.format(*[x]), it gives Tuple Index out of Range

Comment: Remove the brackets form around the `x`

Comment: @Chrystael that's because you're trying to unpack a list with a single element (which just happens to be a list itself) to a function expecting two arguments - it's `*x` not `*[x]`.